# Encrypt string with public key only

Tags: java, android, cryptography, aes

i'm currently working on a android project where i need to encrypt a string using 128 bit AES, padding PKCS7 and CBC. I don't want to use any salt for this.

I've tried loads of different variations including PBEKey but i can't come up with working code. This is what i currently have:

```
String plainText = "24124124123";
String pwd = "BobsPublicPassword";
byte[] key = pwd.getBytes(); 
key = cutArray(key, 16);
byte[] input = plainText.getBytes();
byte[] output = null;
SecretKeySpec keySpec = null;
keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keySpec);
output = cipher.doFinal(input);

private static byte[] cutArray(byte[] arr, int length){
byte[] resultArr = new byte[length];
for(int i = 0; i < length; i++ ){
    resultArr[i] = arr[i];
}
return resultArr;
}
```

Any help appreciated

Comment: So what isn't working with this code?

Comment: Sorry, it gives me the following encrypted string: [B@44f075b0

Comment: That's the `toString()` of a byte array. If you want to peek at the contents, use `Arrays.toString()`.

Comment: This yields: �0�cG��������p I´m beginning to wonder if it´s the part where I´m cutting the array at 16 thats messing up the code. The problem is that when I don't I get an java.security.InvalidKeyException: Key length not 128/192/256 bits.

Answer (score 0):

[B@44f075b0 looks like a object reference. You're returning an array here, sure you're not printing out the memory address of the array instead of it's contents?

Answer (score 0):

Try to print the encrypted data using  `System.out.println("..encrypted data is.."+new String(output));`

It will show you the encrypted string

Comment: Hmm, when I do this I seem to get some kind of encoding error: �0�cG��������p

Answer (score 0):

Consider hashing the pass phrase:

```
        // hash pass one
        byte[] inDigest;
        MessageDigest digester= MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256"); // returns 256bits/ 32 bytes
        byte[] message= password.getBytes("UTF8");  
        digester.update(message); // append message
        inDigest= digester.digest(); // no salt
        byte[] outDigest= new byte[lengthKey];
        for (int i=0; i<lengthKey; i++){ // truncate bytes
            outDigest[i]= inDigest[i];
        }
        return outDigest;
```

In real world code, consider multi hashing the pass phrase.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, your understanding of cryptography is flawed.

You are cutting your 'KEY' in blocks of 16. It is not necessary. But, if you cut anything, you must cut your plaintext to blocks of 16 bytes for AES-128.

Your code may work for the given plain text. But, it will fail once you increase the size of the plaintext.

And regarding the [@B.. part, once encrypted the data will be in byte[] by default. That is the reason you get that. Convert the message to hex format using

http://forums.xkcd.com/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=16666

This will leave the encrypted message in a human readable form that can be displayed on the emulator.

To decrypt, first convert from hex to byte array and then decrypt.

You can use the following links

1- http://www.androidsnippets.com/encryptdecrypt-strings

2- http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Security/AES/AES_v1.html